# Function onTap doesn't work in my custom widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have no idea, why my function doesn't work. Even print statement is not working (print statement is inserted in the first button in "page" code down below). It used to work when my AnswerButton widget wasn't in another file and wasn't a independent widget.

My main question is - why even print statement is not working?

**PAGE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quotes/database/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:quotes/models/quote.dart';
import 'package:quotes/random/random_generator.dart';
import 'package:quotes/requests/network_helper.dart';
import '../answer_buttons.dart';
import '../const.dart';
import 'package:quotes/random/random_generator.dart';
import 'package:quotes/models/character.dart';

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  QuizPage({super.key});
  Quote? randomQuote;
  List<Character> randomCharacter = [];

  RandomGenerator randomQuoteGenerator = RandomGenerator();
  RandomGenerator randomCharacterGenerator = RandomGenerator();

  @override
  State<QuizPage> createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  String? firstname;
  String? lastname;
  int? randomNumber;

  @override
  void initState() {
    () async {
      widget.randomQuote = await getNewQuote();
      setState(() {});
      super.initState();
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(
          child: Text(
            'Guess the Office quote!',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 80.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 10.0),
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(widget.randomQuote?.quote ??
                      'Press a button to continue!')),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 100,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    AnswerButtons(
                      functionOnTap: () async {
                        print('function');
                        Quote newQuote = await getNewQuote();
                        setState(() {
                          widget.randomQuote = newQuote;
                        });
                      },
                      buttonText: '1231',
                    ),
                    AnswerButtons(
                      functionOnTap: () async {
                        Quote newQuote = await getNewQuote();
                        setState(() {
                          widget.randomQuote = newQuote;
                        });
                      },
                      buttonText: '1231',
                    ),
                    AnswerButtons(
                      functionOnTap: () async {
                        Quote newQuote = await getNewQuote();
                        setState(() {
                          widget.randomQuote = newQuote;
                        });
                      },
                      buttonText: '1231',
                    ),
                    AnswerButtons(
                      functionOnTap: () async {
                        Quote newQuote = await getNewQuote();
                        setState(() {
                          widget.randomQuote = newQuote;
                        });
                      },
                      buttonText: '1231',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Quote> getNewQuote() async {
    return widget.randomQuoteGenerator.getRandomObjectFromListWithoutDuplicates(
        await DatabaseHelper.instance.getQuotes());
  }

  Future getNewCharacters() async {
    return widget.randomCharacterGenerator
        .getAListOfRandomNumbersWithoutDuplicates(
            await DatabaseHelper.instance.getCharacters(), 4);
  }
}
```

**CUSTOM WIDGET**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'const.dart';

class AnswerButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnswerButtons(
      {Key? key, required this.functionOnTap, required this.buttonText})
      : super(key: key);
  final String buttonText;
  final Function functionOnTap;
  @override
  _AnswerButtonsState createState() => _AnswerButtonsState();
}

class _AnswerButtonsState extends State<AnswerButtons> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * buttonWidthMultiplier,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * buttonHeightMultiplier,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          widget.functionOnTap;
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(widget.buttonText),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried experimenting with setState and refactoring `Future<Quote> getNewQuote()` to a void function that updates `widget.randomQuote` but none of these worked.

Comment: Hi @Paulinio, In your AnswerButtons class try to change the final Function functionOnTap -- to -->  final VoidCallback functionOnTap;

Comment: Your answer was partially right. I found the solution. Instead of:         `onTap: () {widget.functionOnTap;}`, just use `onTap: widget.functionOnTap,` AND just as you said, Function has to be changed to VoidCallback. Thank you! I would be very thankful if any of you could tell me what's the difference between these two. A function inside a function is still a function, right? @Aks

Comment: Only difference is that VoidCallback returns no data and has no arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your AnswerButtons code:

```
class _AnswerButtonsState extends State<AnswerButtons> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * buttonWidthMultiplier,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * buttonHeightMultiplier,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          // *** This is the problem ***
          widget.functionOnTap;
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(widget.buttonText),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In order to actually call `widget.functionOnTap`, you need to either pass it *directly* to the `onTap` property, or add parentheses to call it within your closure.

So either like this:

```
onTap: widget.functionOnTap,
```

or this:

```
onTap: () {
  widget.functionOnTap();
  //  Add parentheses ^^
},
```

---

*Edit*:

The reason your original code did not work is because you passed a function to `onTap`, but that function didn't actually *do* anything — It simply contained a reference to `widget.functionOnTap`, but did not call it, because the parentheses were missing.

It's the same as if you had a function like this:

```
final x = "foo";

void Function bar() {
  x;
}
```

In this code, `bar()` references `x`, but doesn't do anything with it, so the function is a noop.